# Creating Icons with Square backgrounds using Icons Library?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, icons, tailwind-css

How can you create icons with square backgrounds for your React Native / Expo app, using the common vector icons libraries like in `@expo/vector-icons`?

Examples of such icons are shown on the left side of the "settings" list below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can place your icon in view Component and then style the view according to your need.

```
 <View style={{backgroundColor:"red",borderRadius:3}}>
    <EntypoIcon name='plus' size={25} color={"#fff"} />
  <View>
```

also if you want to make it pressable you can use TouchableOpacity e.g,

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log("i am pressed")}
   style={{backgroundColor:"red",borderRadius:3}}
  >
    <EntypoIcon name='plus' size={25} color={"#fff"} />
  <TouchableOpacity>
```